# Error While Updating property "edges" of a view managed by RNCSafeAreaView in react native

Tags: react-native

Error: `"Error While Updating property "edges" of a view managed by RNCSafeAreaView"`

At first page somehow loads without error, But When I reload it i get this error.

```
import React from 'react'
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

import SearchBar from './SearchBar';

const Homepage = ()=>{

  return (
    <SafeAreaView edges={['top']}>
        <SearchBar/>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

export default Homepage;
```

i tried clearing cache, updating 'react-native-safe-area-context' to latest version, nothing Worked

Comment: @TheBlindHawk Sorry about that, but it's in the title "Error While Updating property "edges" of a view managed by RNCSafeAreaView"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved the By Downgrading the 'react-native-safe-area-context' library to version 4.0.0

cmd: `npm install react-native-safe-area-context@4.0.0`

Comment: probably a new version bug then, if you wan you could try opening an issue on their github repo https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context/issues

Comment: The error was introduced between versions 4.5.3 and 6.0.0 of 'react-native-safe-area-context' library, somewhere in this code:
https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context/compare/7b27187..b8b1e8e

Answer (score 1):

For me this happened after I ran `npx expo install expo-dev-client` and I had an old out of date Expo development build installed on my device.

This was the full error message I had in case other people have the same problem and are searching the internet for a solution:

```
There was a problem loading the project

This development build encountered the following error

Error while updating property 'edges' of a view managed by: RNCSafeAreaView

com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap cannot be cast to
com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableArray
```

Solution is to search your device for an icon for your app and uninstall it (this is the old development build). [Then create a new development build and install it on your device](https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/create-a-build/). Then close Expo if it is running and run it again using `npx expo start --dev-client`

Answer (score 0):

Been using react-native-safe-area-context 4.7.4 - seems this version is broken.

App crashed as soon as rendering

Tested 4.5.3 - worked.
Tested 4.7.4 - app crashes.
Tested 4.8.4 - worked.

You can check your exact version in node-modules/react-native-safe-area-context/package.json